# filling my array with random values C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm trying to make a simple battle ship game. I'm stuck on trying to randomly place the ships on my board.I have a feeling it is because I should be using a vector instead of an array. but I'm not sure how to create a 2d vector.

Here's what I have so far:

```
using namespace std;



void clearBoard(const int row, const int col) 
{
    int grid[row][col];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col;j++) {
            grid[i][j] = 0;
            cout << grid[i][j] << " ";

        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void setShips(int max_ships1, int row, int col)
{
    int ship_counter = 0;
    while(ship_counter < max_ships1) {
        int x = rand() % row;
        int y = rand() % col;
        int matrix[x][y]
        if (matrix[x][y] != 1) {
            ship_counter++;
            matrix[x][y] = 1;
            cout << matrix[x][y] << " ";
        }
    cout << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    int _row = atoi(argv[0]);
    int _col = atoi(argv[2]);

    int max_ships;
    if (_row > _col) {
        max_ships = _row;
    }
    else if (_col > _row) {
        max_ships = _col;
    }
    else {
        max_ships = _row;
    }

    cout << "enter the size of the board:";
    cin >> _row >> _col;
    clearBoard(_row, _col);
    setShips(_row,_col,max_ships);





    return 0;

}
```

If the user decides on a 3x3 board, the first function returns:

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

I'm hoping to randomly generate 1's to represent a battleship's position.
Here's an example on a 3x3 board:

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
1 0 0
```

Thanks.

Comment: `int _row = atoi(argv[0]);` Did you mean `argv[1]`?

Comment: Don't think so. I want the user to enter the board size like "4 4", with a space in between.

Comment: This is not how `argv` represent command line arguments. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3024202.

Comment: 2d vector: std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid(row, std::vector<int>(col))

Comment: `argv[0]` is the name of your program. `argv[1]` is the first argument.

Comment: If your program is run as `./a.out 4 6`, then `argv[0]` is `"./a.out"`, `argv[1]` is `"4"`, and `argv[2]` is `"6"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that `grid` goes out of scope (and is effectively deleted) when `clearBoard` returns, and `matrix` (a completely unrelated array to `grid`) goes out of scope each time through your `while` loop. That means that you're filling `grid` with zeroes, then creating a bunch of other arrays with random data and sometimes setting one element to 1. You need to either make `grid` global, or return it from `clearBoard` and pass it to `setShips` as an argument.

Passing around multidimensional raw arrays is kind of complicated, so using a vector might make this a bit easier for you if you don't want to make the array global. To create a two-dimensional vector, you might think that `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` will work, but that's not quite right. You *can* do it that way, as mentioned in the comments, but technically, `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` is what's called a *jagged array*, meaning that you can have each row be a different length - unlike your raw 2D array, where you know that each row must always be the same length.

The proper way to make a two-dimensional array with a `vector` is this:

```
std::vector<int> grid(row * col);
grid[i * row + j] = 1; // Or i * col + j will also work.
```

As you can see, it's a bit more complicated to get an element out by its (x,y) coordinates. It doesn't matter which of the two calculation methods you use, but in one version `i` is `x` and `j` is `y`, while in the other, the reverse is true (`i` is `y`, etc).

Comment: Thanks, I just have one question about implementation. Once I declare `std::vector<int> grid(row * col);`, should set `grid[i * row + j] = 1;` in setShips and `grid[i * row + j] = 0;` in clearBoard? Sorry to ask, grabbing the elements is slightly confusing to me.

Comment: Pretty much, but don't forget that you need to do that on the _same object_, unlike in the code you posted (as my first paragraph says).

Comment: When I declared `std::vector<int> grid(row * col);` in my function, it says that vector of type <int> does not have a call operator. I tried changing the return type of the function from void to int, but still the same error. I tried declaring the array global, but I get the error: `Floating point exception: 8`. Very sorry to bother you like this but I'm new to programming and don't really have anyone that can help me.

Comment: You must be doing something else wrong, because that statement `std::vector<int> grid(row * col);` is correct and has nothing to do with call operators.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set up a 2D vector like this :

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    std::vector< std::vector<int> > grid2D;

    //m * n is the size of the grid

    int m = 10;
    int n = 10;

    //Grow rows by m
    grid2D.resize(m);

   //Grow Columns by n
    for(int i = 0 ; i < m ; ++i) grid2D[i].resize(n);

  // print out 2D grid on screen
    for(i = 0 ; i < m ; ++i){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < n ; ++j){       

            grid2D[i][j]=0;
            cout<<""<<grid2D[i][j]<<" ";

        }
        cout<<"\n";

    }
    cout<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```